# Unpacking a std tuple into pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a tuple

```
std::tuple<A, B, C> myFavoriteTuple;
```

I can do this:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = myFavoriteTuple
```

But if some of these tuples are really expensive to copy, what I'd really like is to take a reference or a pointer to the right spots in my tuple. I can do this:

```
A* a = &std::get<0>(myFavoriteTuple);
B* b = &std::get<1>(myFavoriteTuple);
C* c = &std::get<2>(myFavoriteTuple);
```

But that seems so lame compared to how awesome the `tie` syntax is. Is there any other way to get pointers/references to the tuple components?

Comment: Moving from tuple might be best idea in some cases - `std::tie(a, b, c) = std::move(myFavoriteTuple);`

Comment: Oh man, C++17 is great: `auto&& [a, b, c] = myFavoriteTuple;` done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the usual indices infrastructure:

```
template<int... Is>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

template<int... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> { };
```

You could create a function that returns a tuple of pointers, each element being a pointer to the corresponding element of the input tuple:

```
template<typename... Args, int... Is>
auto make_pointer_tuple(std::tuple<Args...>& t, seq<Is...>)
    -> std::tuple<typename std::add_pointer<Args>::type...>
{
    return std::make_tuple(&std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template<typename... Args>
auto make_pointer_tuple(std::tuple<Args...>& t)
    -> std::tuple<typename std::add_pointer<Args>::type...>
{
    return make_pointer_tuple(t, gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>());
}
```

And this is how you could use it:

```
std::tuple<int, bool, std::string> myFavoriteTuple{0, false, ""};

int* pInt = nullptr;
bool* pBool = nullptr;
std::string* pString = nullptr;
tie(pInt, pBool, pString) = make_pointer_tuple(myFavoriteTuple);
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/BCIQUa).

Comment: Wondering if this proposal would make it better?
http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html

Comment: @balki: Yep, that will standardize the indices machinery

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
template<typename T>
struct ptie
{
    const T *ptr;
    ptie()
        :ptr(nullptr)
    {}

    void operator=(const T &x)
    {
        ptr = &x;
    }
};

ptie<A> a;
ptie<B> b;
ptie<C> c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = myFavoriteTuple;
```

Then you can use `*a.ptr` to access the object. You can even override `operator->` etc. if you feel like it.

The main drawback of this method is that it bind the tuple members as `const`, because of the `operator=(const T&)`. You could remove it with `ptr = const_cast<T*>(x)` but I think that could break the const-correctness in some cases.